# How do you hide App Store app updates that your version of iOS does not support?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I am running a first generation iPad with iOS 5.1.1 (the most recent version it will ever have) and I just noticed today that the application [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/) has just dropped support for iOS 5 on the latest version of their app. Seeing that this is probably going to be a first of many apps, is there a way to hide updates that can't be installed on your current version of iOS, so that only updates that is compatible with iOS 5 (and my iPad)  will be displayed in the list of updates in the App Store?

This could get kind of messy in the App Store update list with a future shuffled mess of things that I can or can't upgrade or even worse a complete list of stuff that I can't upgrade to too! Are there any work around or fixes to hide that impending mess?

[image: Shazam an iOS app you can't install on iOS 5]

Comment: This is kind of silly, apple is not showing me a upgrade to iOS6 button that is grayed out in software update "Settings", why show me stuff in the App Store that I can't upgrade too.  I am surprised I am not seeing a "Buy new iDevice" button linking to the Apple Store.

Comment: That would be hilarious. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a real answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a hard question. On the one hand, it's in Apple's interest to ensure all users know that the developer has a new version and you are now dropping off the upgrade path for an app you may use for work or just really love to use. On the other hand, this becomes a pain if you always have to see an update you don't ever care to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide them yet but, you will be able to download the lastest version of an app that worked on your version of iOS. Apple recently addressed this problem with some changes made to the iOS app store.

As noted here [Apple now offering older iOS device owners 'last compatible version' of apps](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/09/17/apple-now-offering-older-ios-device-owners-last-compatible-vers/)

[image]

> Apple has begun offering owners of older iOS devices the "last compatible version" of apps that will run on their device, as noticed by Reddit members. For example, if an iPhone 3G owner tries to download the latest Twitter app, a dialog box will pop up alerting them that the most recent version of the app is not compatible with their device, but they can opt to download the last version that will run.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug that has been present for years. There unfortunately isn't a way to stop getting notification updates, unless you uninstall the app, which you really shouldn't have to do. Lets hope this bug is fixed soon, you can tell them about it here:
[apple.com/support/feedback/](https://ssl.apple.com/support/feedback/)

Answer (score 1):

Apple is trying to "force" everyone to update - currently, there is **no** solution to this.